# How to monitor filebeat stats with metricbeat

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat, elk, metricbeat, elastic-beats

I'm trying to setup metricbeat to monitor filebeat stats. But when I tried the beats module for doing so in my metricbeat config, I'm getting this error:

error message from metricbeat logs:

> Error fetching data for metricset beat.stats: error making http request: Get http://filebeat_ip:5044/stats: dial tcp filebeat_ip:5044: connect: connection refused

metricbeat.yml file

```
metricbeat.modules:
  - module: beat
    metricsets:
      - stats
      - state
    period: 10s
    hosts: ["filebeat_ip:5044"]
```

where filebeat_ip is the ip where my filebeat is running, which's the same machine as my metricbeat.

Can someone please help me as to why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same machine I would just use localhost or 127.0.0.1.

PS: If not running on localhost, I'd double check if the port is actually reachable and not blocked by a firewall. Something like `telnet <ip> 5044` should be a quick sanity check.